# How to pass an action to be performed on some XElement as a parameter?

Tags: c#, json, xml, xpath

Forgive the confusing question wording I lacked enough space to describe it clearly.

We have a library function `SerializeXelement` that takes an XElement that is the root of some XML structure, does a processing step, and returns it in JSON format.

This processing step is a specific step for a single purpose (adding an attribute to specific elements, specified by an array argument of xpaths passed to this function `IEnumerable<string> ensureNodeArray = null`
(this function is shown below, as described above).

I have recently required this function to perform another different processing step, so I've overloaded this function by adding another string collection of xpaths, for which the `SerializeXelement` calls another helper function to process.

I wonder if there is a better way to handle this in case of many future processing steps.

**The question is:** is there anything in c# to help facilitate me passing a collection of anonymous functions to be performed on a set of specific xml elements? So that each application using this library function (there are many, and they use it quite differently) can choose what is done to the XML document before being converted to JSON?

Library functions described above:

```
public static string SerializeXelement(XElement xEl, IEnumerable<string> ensureNodeArray = null, 
    bool removeAttrSymbol = true, Formatting formatting = Formatting.None, bool omitRootObject = false)
{
    if (ensureNodeArray != null)
    {
        AddArrayAttributes(xEl, ensureNodeArray);
    }

    var output = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xEl, formatting, omitRootObject);
    if (removeAttrSymbol) { output = output.RemoveJsonXmlAttributeSymbols(); }
    return output;
}

private static void AddArrayAttributes(XElement xEl, IEnumerable<string> nodeArray)
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json";
    xEl.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "json", ns));

    // Add array attribute to all relevent nodes
    foreach (var nde in nodeArray.Select(xEl.XPathSelectElements).SelectMany(ndes =>
    {
        var xElements = ndes as XElement[] ?? ndes.ToArray();
        return xElements;
    }))
    {
        nde.Add(new XAttribute(ns + "Array", "true"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Probably better suited for `Code Review`

Comment: @MethodMan I disagree I may have gone into more detail than necessary  to give the reader the complete context but the question itself is concise

Comment: could you not make a Delegate for that Action..?

Answer (score 3):

Pass your xml processor as an `Action` the call it.

```
public static string SerializeXelement(Action<XElement, IEnumerable<string>> xmlProcessor, XElement xEl, IEnumerable<string> ensureNodeArray = null, 
    bool removeAttrSymbol = true, Formatting formatting = Formatting.None, bool omitRootObject = false)
{
    if (xmlProcessor != null)
    {
        xmlProcessor(xEl, ensureNodeArray);
    }

    var output = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xEl, formatting, omitRootObject);
    if (removeAttrSymbol) { output = output.RemoveJsonXmlAttributeSymbols(); }
    return output;
}
```

Usage:

```
SerializeXelement(AddArrayAttributes, xmlRoot, ...);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking too based on the OP's title and problem description. The only thing I'd change is to make it a List<Action<XElement, IEnumerable<string>>> so that he can pass an arbitrary collection of actions.

Comment: @Jakotheshadows - passing a list of actions isn't necessary.  Since actions are multicast delegates you can just add them to get the same effect, i.e. `var xmlProcessor = xmlProcessor2 + xmlProcessor1`

Comment: Hamlet I need to be able to pass a different `IEnumerable<string>` for each action. It is a collection of xpath strings specifying which XML elements to perform that action on. It will be a different collection for each action. How can I do that?